# Oracle apex- how to add text to existing process error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to know if I can add my own text to an error that occurs when running process. Currently, the only 2 options are showing the sql error or replacing the error with my own text, but not add my text to the error text.
I will show an example:

I have a modal dialog page with process type - "Form-Automatic Row  Processing" after clicking the "Save" button:
[image]

On inserting id to identity column I get the approproate sql error:

[image]

And when I fill the "Error Message" in the process in page designer:

[image]

In the modal dialog I get the error (as expected):

[image]

But I want to combine those texts, with a simple solution, and not complicate the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the page help for the process error message, it states that you can use substitution strings #SQLERRM_TEXT# and #SQLERRM# to fine tune the error message.